# PHP - make if statement with two statements shorter

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following If statement and I want to make it shorter (eg. a one liner), without writing my if statement in one line.

```
    if ($start + $count > $total) {
        $count = $total;
    }
```

Basically I want to achieve that `$count` + `$total` is never higher then `$total` and if this is the case I want to set `$count` equal to `$total`.

Comment: You want to make it a one liner without writing it in one line?

Comment: I meant I do not want to write my if statement into one line just to make it a one liner. I meant to have a different solution then just write my code into one line. Maybe this was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `min()` for that:

```
$count = min($total, $start + $count);
```

Comment: This assumes a non-existing `$count = $start + $count;` on the `else` branch of the original `if`.

Comment: @axiac From OP statement `achieve that $count + $total is never higher then $total` you can see that there is some *else* part elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called a ternary operation.

```
$count = (($start + $count) > $total ? $total : null);
```

References:
https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

```
 $count = ($total < $start+$count) ? $total : $count;
```

This puts the if-logic in one line.